Is there a way to use Google ML Kit to scan multiple QR codes simultaneously?
I’m working on an Android application where I need to scan multiple QR codes at once (e.g., up to 10 QR codes in a single frame detect and decode at the same time). I’m considering using Google ML Kit's Barcode Scanning API, but I’m not sure if it supports detecting and decoding multiple QR codes in a single camera frame.
Here’s what I’d like to achieve:
- Detect and decode up to 10 QR codes simultaneously.
- Process the results efficiently for real-time feedback.

What I’ve tried:
- I’ve reviewed the ML Kit Barcode Scanning API documentation, but it’s not clear whether this functionality is supported out of the box.
- I tested the API with single QR codes, and it works perfectly for one barcode or QR code at a time.
- I attempted scanning multiple QR codes by feeding a frame containing multiple codes, but it seems to detect only one at a time.

My Questions:
- Does Google ML Kit Barcode Scanning API natively support multiple QR code detection?
- If not, is there any open-source implementation or workaround to achieve this functionality using ML Kit or another library (e.g., Zxing or ZBar)?
- Are there specific configurations or techniques to enhance the detection of multiple barcodes/QR codes in one frame?

Additional Details:
- Development environment: Android (Java/Kotlin)
- Library version: Google ML Kit Barcode Scanning (latest version as of writing)
- Use case: Real-time scanning of bulk QR codes (up to 10) in a single camera frame.

If ML Kit is not the right choice for this use case, I’d appreciate any recommendations for other libraries or approaches that could help achieve this.
Thank you!

formatting is broken. bullet points aren't code. the [code block] article shows you how markdown formatting works.
